# How can I configure Jenkins to cycle through my projects continuously?

Tags: jenkins

I have a dedicated Jenkins server that I am using to kick off build-and-static-analysis jobs. I want to make sure that the server is highly utilized but I also want to make sure that no single project is monopolizing the build and scan time. How can I configure Jenkins to cycle through my projects in a round robin fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [priority sorter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) plugin